# What do you do if the hole in the tile is larger than the shower faucet escutcheon?

Tags: shower, tile

Whoever built this shower stall really made a hack job of the hole for the shower faucet.  The hole is actually just a bit larger than the escutcheon on the upper right corner.  One option is to just caulk the heck out of it and hope for the best.  Is there a better approach?

[image]

Comment: Wow............

Comment: More like, meh. Take *your* escussion off and see how butchered the hole is. (that crack tho...)

Comment: Is that Symmons product a remodeling plate or all one piece.

Comment: Was there supposed to be an escutcheon in the upper rigjt corner? Did you post the wrong photo?

Answer (score 7):

Some vendors offer over sized escutcheons for this purpose. I found one available from Symmons. It was for their shower faucet, but I used it on a Moen. It's just a matter of how it is mounted.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I see several possible options.

1. Find a flat round chrome plate piece that is larger diameter than your escutcheon. Cut a hole in it to fit around the projection part of the faucet and secure it against the wall behind the escutcheon. seal around the edge with clear silicone.
2. Similar to above but make your own ring from some brass sheet material. Polish it up and apply a clear lacquer to the surface to seal it. Then install as above.
3. Remove the tile with the over aggressive cutout and replace with another that has less cutout. This works if there was spare tile left at the site after the original job was completed or if the tile is easy to source.

Answer (score 0):

... and one of them is cracked. Either re-do those two tiles, or:

Shove some backing (newspaper, paper towel, w/e) in there and **get a little grout** to shore-up those exposed corners. DO NOT fill the area entirely with grout. Seal it, put escussion, and caulk. A picture with the escussion on would tell me if you can get away with that (looking at the old outline tells me it's a no-brainer).

Comment: this is a shower.  How will the newspaper/paper towel hold in there at the first sign of moisture?

Comment: @QuocVu - it doesn't matter. It just has to be there until the grout cures. It's so half of it doesn't fall down into the wall. Once it's cured, pull out any excess backing... or not.

Comment: and grout does crack.  Nothing will be holding things in place.

Comment: @QuocVu - look at the old outline. It needs like a 1/4" pebble of grout in the top and bottom right corners. Using backing is so that you can get enough in there so that it keys into behind the three adjacent tiles. Without backing it will fall down into the wall or slump before it cures. - Meaning you need a 1" ball of grout stuck to the inside like gum, with a 1/4" showing, then smushed flush to the surface. But if you can mix your grout to a consistency where you don't need backing; all the better.

Comment: I get your point now @Mazura.  I would use thinset instead of grout though. From my experience, grout doesn't hold well unless it is sandwiched between tiles.

Comment: It's all Portland cement. Grout just has colorant and sometimes no sand.